# Concatenar dos sentencias diferentes en una misma línea de código

Tags: haskell, sentencias

De un sitio web extraje esta función remover primer elemento de la lista

```
eliminarPrimero :: [a] -> [a]
eliminarPrimero = \miLista ->
    case miLista of
        [] -> []
        x:xs -> xs
```

Luego, modifiqué la función para que en lugar de eliminar el primer elemento, elimine el último

```
eliminarÚltimo :: [a] -> [a]
eliminarÚltimo = \miLista ->
    case miLista of
        [] -> error "Lista vacía"
        [x] -> []
        x:xs -> x : (eliminarÚltimo xs)
```

¿Hay alguna forma de "fusionar" ambas funciones en una para que una misma función haga las dos acciones (eliminar el primer y último elemento) a la vez?

Pruebo con esto:

```
eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo :: [a] -> [a]
eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo = \miLista ->
    case miLista of
        [] -> error "Lista vacía"
        [x] -> x 
        x:xs -> x : (eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo xs) and (eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo xs)
```

¿Hay algún operador para concatenar sentencias en Haskell?

Comment: `eliminarPrimero (eliminarÚltimo xs)`

Comment: La idea es usar la función eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo solamente, las otras las puse como parte de la letra.

Comment: Tanto el título como la pregunta final habla de _"concatenar"_ sentencias. Por otro lado, ¿qué prolema hay para combinar dos funciones que ya funcionan? Y por último, ¿por qué no usas las funciones que tiene haskell para listas como `tail` o `init`?

Comment: No es que haya un problema. Quiero independizar la función `eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo` y que ella sola haga ambas funciones sin depender de otra. Esto lo hago para principalmente ahorrar líneas de código. También quiero prescindir en lo más posiible de funciones predefinidas.

Comment: x : (eliminarÚltimo xs) elimina el último elemento de la lista y (eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo xs) elimina el primero. Quisiera alguna forma de que estas dos sentencias se ejecutan a la vez en una misma instrucción.

Comment: Sigo sin comprender para qué. Si quieres ahorrar líneas de código, para eso están las funciones estándar para manejo de listas: `eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo = init . tail`, una sóla línea. Además, haskell usa la _evaluación perezosa_, lo que quiere decir que combinar dos funciones no es aplicar la primera sobre toda la lista y luego aplica la segunda sobre el primer resultado. Ambas funciones se aplican a la vez. Es más, las listas pueden ser infinitas y seguirían funcionando. Querer hacerlo todo revuelto en una sóla función implica usar estados, nada sencillo cuando no puedes usar variables.

Comment: Bueno, está bien lo dejo así. Me funciona si. Hice  `x:xs -> eliminarPrimero (x: eliminarÚltimo xs)` y `saqué  [x] -> x`  porque es instrucción contradictoria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Haskell, no existe un operador para concatenar declaraciones como se puede encontrar en los lenguajes imperativos. En cambio, este lenguaje se basa en expresiones y composición de funciones para lograr resultados similares.

El código que posteé para eliminarPrimeroyÚltimo no es sintácticamente correcto y lo que, si bien en papel sí compila, no lo hace en máquina. La palabra clave and se utiliza para conjunciones lógicas en expresiones booleanas, no para concatenar o combinar funciones.

Para fusionar las funciones que puse eliminarPrimero y eliminarÚltimo en una función que elimine tanto el primer como el último elemento de una lista, puede hacer coincidir patrones en la lista para manejar diferentes casos. Así es como se podría escribir una función de este tipo:

```
-- | Removes the first and last elements from a list.
-- If the list has fewer than two elements, it returns an empty list.
deleteFirstAndLast :: [a] -> [a]
deleteFirstAndLast myList = case myList of
    [] -> [] -- The list is empty, return an empty list.
    [_] -> [] -- The list has only one element, return an empty list.
    (x:xs) -> init xs -- Remove the first element and then call `init` to remove the last element.
```

La función init es una función de biblioteca estándar que elimina el último elemento de una lista. Si la lista está vacía, provocará un error, por lo que manejamos los casos de lista vacía y lista de un solo elemento por separado.